# RMI compiler generates broken stub for EJB 2.1

Tags: java, eclipse, ejb, rmi, rad

Adding a new method to a stateless EJB(2.1) and promoting it to the Remote interface through the Rad 8 UI leads to the RMI compiler generating a broken EJB _Stub.

Java Compiler Error: The type _ChoiceApplicationService_Stub must implement the inherited abstract method ChoiceApplicationService.updateSeatsData(SeatsUpdate)

I deleted the stub several times and had Rad reinvoke the RMIC atleast 10 times with no success. I shut down RAD and restarted it with the -clean directive several times with no success.

Has anyone had a problem with the Stub generation in Rad/Exclipse and knows what could cause this? Unfortunately the EJB is broken with a bad Stub and i cant even address it by fixing the stub since it will be overwritten.

Edit: It looks like Rad 8/Eclipse has a hidden file cached somewhere. No matter what i promote/demote or manually add to the Service Interface the generated stub is identical every time.

Edit2: When demoting methods it also produces a faulty Tie that still has all the 'cached' methods in it: _EJSRemoteStatelessChoiceApplicationService_77509b5e_Tie

Edit3: Brand new workspace same problem, but it works on our Build machine ...

Comment: You will have to tell us what is broken about this message.

Comment: The fact that the method from the Remote interface is not being implemented by the stub that is generated through RAD. Which results in a regular compiler error just like when forgetting to implement a method from an interface. Unfortunately the stub is generated through RMIC so i have no way of fixing the stub myself.

Comment: I would say RMIC is working on an old version of the interface.

Comment: Looks like it but i cant figure out how and why. Even creating a new workspace and a copy of the project produced the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesnt really solve the problem i had, but i ended up creating a new EJB 3 project recreating the configuration files and copy over the java source code. I can build again and as a nice side effect i am using the latest EAR, EJB etc. version.